# How to save history of my previous bitcoin wallet?

Tags: transactions, history

I have 2 bitcoin wallets. Let's call them "old" and "new". I been using my old wallet for many years, it contains long history of buying and selling BTC. Now I decided to use my new wallet, so I moved all BTC from old to new.

If I look to my new wallet's history, I can see there only 4 big incoming transactions I made last month - it's not enough to prove that I was holding this BTC for many years and didn't bought it month ago.

If some goverment authorities will ask me where and how I bought my BTC, I want to be able to show them all my history from "old" wallet to prove that I bought it many years ago for small price.

I have access to my old wallet and can see all history there, but this wallet's app is not maintained yet, so I worry that this app can die in future, so I need to save all my transactions somehow.

I can save all links to https://live.blockcypher.com/ from my old wallet, but is it enough to prove all transactions if i will loose access to old wallet in future?

---

UPD: my old wallet is this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.btcontract.wallet

new wallet is Electrum

Comment: Which wallet is your old wallet? Please provide as much detail as possible (name, version, authors, platform, ...).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, updated my question with app info